# Custom JComponent does not work with flow layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I created a class extending `JComponent` and want to use it on a `JPanel`. If I set its bounds, I can not use it in `FlowLayout` the way I want; it appears on `JPanel` as if it was using absolute positioning. If I don't specify the bounds, it does not appear at all. What could be the solution?

Thanks.

`JMotor.java`:

```
public class JMotor extends JComponent {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        BufferedImage img = null;

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("motor.jpg"));
        } 

        catch (Exception e) {

        }

        g2.drawImage(img, 5, 5, this);
        //setBounds(5, 5, 100, 50);
    }
}
```

`Scada.java`:

```
public class Scada {

    JFrame scadaFrame;
    JPanel scadaPanel;

    Scada () {

        scadaFrame = new JFrame("Scada");
        scadaFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        scadaPanel = new JPanel();          

        scadaPanel.add(new JSuruculuMotor());
        scadaPanel.add(new JMotor());

        scadaFrame.setContentPane(scadaPanel);
        scadaFrame.setSize(600,300);    
        scadaFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Scada();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a JPanel instead of JComponent and paint your image on it?

Comment: Btw, you could also just (delete the custom panel and) use a `new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imagePath))`, if you don't need the panel for anything else.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yep, that's what I was thinking of. Luckily camickr already added that in his answer too.

Comment: @LuxxMiner *"Luckily camickr already added that in his answer too."*  LOL..  Hadn't noticed that!

Comment: In the future don't load resources inside your paint method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because FlowLayout respects the preferred size of the component and you have not specified the preferred size of your custom component.

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your class to return its size to the layout managers can do their job.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method. Also, don't do I/O in a painting method. The image should be read in the constructor of the class.

However, the question is why are you creating a custom component? Just use a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`.

If you want the image to appear 5 pixels from the top/left then you add a Border to the label:

```
label.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5) );
```